# How to separate interfaces names

Tags: python, regex

As a result of my bash 'ip link show' command I got a string which contains list of all my ip interfaces.
I want to somehow separate the names of each single interfaces name.
Here is the string:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp7s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether f0:76:1c:35:7b:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
link/ether ac:b5:7d:0f:2d:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Names of the interfaces may vary. Currently they are: lo, enp7s0f1, wlp8s0.

I tried to split the string with the regex:

```
[0-9]{2}[:]|[0-9]{1}[:]
```

And then, after 1:, 2:, 3: first thing will be interface names but it also splits me MAC addresses and generate a mess.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something as simple as this?

```
(?<=\d: )\w+
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dnFj3F/1)

Explanation:

```
(?<=\d: )   Positive lookbehind - start with a number, then : and whitespace, but this is not captured.
\w+         Match all [a-zA-Z0-9], so until the next :
```

Comment: Bingo, you are a regex master!

Answer (score 0):

*`[user@localhost ~]# ip link show | cut -f 2 -d ":" | grep -v [0-9][0-9]`*

The above command should be suffice to grep output required by you.